# Android Studio after updating to build tools 19.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, updates

Just upgraded my Android build tools version to 19.1.0 and this is what I am getting:

> Unsupported method: Dependencies.getJars().
>             The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>             To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>             Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.: Unsupported method:
>   Dependencies.getJars().

I searched all my libraries and dependancies and all is set to 19.1.0

What am I missing?

Comment: where did you get 19.1.0 from?  Android studio is at 0.5.2 and gradle is at 1.12.  So that might be your problem?

Comment: @edthethird - he is probably referring to the build tools which are currently on version 19.1.0

Comment: @edthethird - latest:
SDK Build-tools: v19.1;
Android Studio: v0.5.9

Comment: Can you post the gradle file that is calling getJars()?

Comment: Pot the build.gradle , you as/android-plugin/gradle version.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Version 0.11 of the Android Gradle plugin was just released (6/6/14). Change your build.gradle settings to "0.10.+".

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
```

Note: This should be *considered a temporary solution* until you can update Android Studio and your Android SDK (particularly your build tools).

Comment: Berdon, thanks. This works for Intellij Idea as well.

Comment: Also don't forget to update Android Studio if you haven't yet.

Comment: Uhm..what? v0.11 is released, so you suggest to downgrade to 0.10? That's not a solution, that's a temporary workaround that gradually will increase compatibility problems.

Comment: I've downgrade to com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+ and I continue having this problem. :-(

Answer (score 3):

Updated Android Studio that resolved the problem.

Comment: Like answer of Yuki, it is better to tell which version are you using.

Answer (score 2):

this error occurs at IntelliJ IDEA, too.
and I try some version of IntelliJ IDE

build tool 19.1.0 and gradle plugin 0.11

- Android Studio 0.8.1 : build success
- IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 : this error still occurs at IU-135.760
- IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 EAP : this error still occurs at IU-135.1019
- IntelliJ IDEA 14 EAP : build success at IU-138.777

I can't find this fix in 14 EAP's release note, but it seems to be fixed at 14 EAP.